# In GraphQL schema, how can a field be GraphQLString as well as GraphQLInt?

Tags: graphql, relayjs, relay, graphql-js

Here's my code from the express application for GraphQL schema:-

```
let data = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name:"Data",
    fields: {
        id: {type: GraphQLID},
        value: {type: GraphQLString} // TODO: allow for string as well as int
    }
});
```

How can I make 'value' field accept a string value as well as int value so that it can be stored using the correct type?

Comment: okay if you made value `integer` as well as `string` then, what type will you consider for database

Comment: @p0k8_ The point of GraphQL is to hide database details. It does not matter if this value comes from database A or B or some file or other API. So it is perfectly valid to have union types

Comment: graphql provides `int` but the database schema for the type is `string` then ??

Comment: It is a nosql database which can store json objects directly. Hence a string will be saved as string and an int as int.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment saying that you use NoSQL database which can place both strings and ints in the same field, you should go with `GraphQLString`. When creating new instance of above object, you can create a `resolve` method for `value` field, which would check if passed value is `string` or `int` (of course it would always be string because of `GraphQLString` type, however it can be a string like `"123"` which can be parsed to int) - according to this you can perform some parsing before saving in the database. 
On the other hand, when you will retrieve the data from database, it will always occur as a `string` in the graphql representation - if this is not a case I think that this could be a simple solution.

However, if you are not satisfied with this proposition, I am afraid that you can't trick GraphQL as you want to. Every field can obtain only single type definition.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:
This solution is not valid for the question. It works only for object types and not scalars**

You should look at `GraphQLUnionType`: http://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqluniontype

I'm not used to define types like this, but I expect it to be something like the below:

```
var ValueType = new GraphQLUnionType({
  name: 'Value',
  types: [ GraphQLString, GraphQLInt ],
  resolveType(value) {
    if (value instanceof string) {
      return GraphQLString;
    }
    if (value instanceof number) {
      return GraphQLInt;
    }
  }
});

let data = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name:"Data",
    fields: {
        id: {type: GraphQLID},
        value: {type: ValueType}
    }
});
```

Comment: `UnionType` can only have object types, it cannot contain Type like `String` or `Int`

Comment: My mistaken. I missed the non-scalar part of this. I see this issue regarding the use case: https://github.com/facebook/graphql/issues/215

Comment: I think it is misleading for this answer to receive an upvote since it doesn't work for this case. I request for it to be set as 0 again. I don't have enough reputation yet to make this change.

Comment: I agree with @NikhilAgarwal on the up-vote. This is not meaning-full.